# Is Oracle ODP.NET stable for Production?

Tags: c#

I've been wandering on the net and I encountered a lot of message like this one
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090530102105/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/rakker/archive/2006/10/31/95640.aspx)

ODP.NET and it's stability.
Wow, ODP.NET 10.2.0.20 is not horribly stable yet.

I find rather astonishing that such big editor releases a product that is not stable but it seems so, so should ODP be used ? Is there anything more sure ?

Answer (score 2):

I always had the impression that Oracle doesn't care a great deal about .NET and MS technologies in general (which is understandable). ODP.NET doesn't fit the ADO.NET 2.0 model very well (the way it handles transactions, command parameters bound by order rather than name...). But anyway, since Microsoft has deprecated its own Oracle provider (System.Data.Oracle), you don't really have a choice... Sure, there are third party ADO.NET providers for Oracle (like the one from [DevArt](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/)), but they're not free. So if you want a free ADO.NET Oracle provider, you're stuck with ODP.NET anyway

To answer the question more directly : I wouldn't say that ODP.NET is not stable. It might have a few bugs, but it's very widely used in production environments all over the world, which wouldn't be the case if it was really unstable. So I'd say it's quite unlikely that you will encounter major bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The post you are quoting is 2 years old. Current stable version is 11.1.0.7.20. I haven't used it personally but I would use it for production.

If there will be problems with that (or any other components of your application) the testing should find the problems before deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest stable version from Oracle's site. But even then you'd realize that there are still connection leaks. Even though the following steps might not solve your problems completely, they certainly help:

1. Use the using(){} construct
2. Write a batch process to drop all connection to your db on a regular basis. In my experience every other week for a VERY BUSY website.

Let me know if there is a better way!